# How should I configure a router, a bridge and an access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Sorry for [my last](https://superuser.com/questions/1824624/how-should-i-configure-a-router-a-bridge-and-an-access-point) post I added more information here.

The idea for this setup is the following: since the main modem router is far away from me, the second one is just a bridge I don’t use it but it is necessary for the third one.

These are the routers:

- [TP-Link TD-W8961NADSL](https://www.tp-link.com/in/home-networking/dsl-modem-router/td-w8961n/)
- [Netis WF2419](https://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/de_details/id/1/de/168.html)
- [D-Link DSL-2750B](https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/products/dsl-2750b-wireless-n-adsl2-plus-modem-router)

The main router is TP-Link TD-W8961NADSL modem router.

The second is Netis WF2419. I don’t know if it’s an access point or repeater, connected to the main router via wireless wan because I can't use a cable. But the signal is very strong; I tested it by ping.

WAN wireless:

> [image: WAN wireless.]

Connection with main:

> [image: Connection with main.]

It acts like a router:

> [image: It acts like a router.]

Those devices are connected to the third one.

Router or bridge:

> [image: Router or bridge.]

Bridge mode:

> [image: Bridge mode]

Those options showed when I switched to bridge mode.

The third one is a D-Link DSL-2750B router. I use it like an access point

Bridged:

> [image: Bridged.]

DHCP disabled:

> [image: DHCP disabled.]

When I use the bridge mode in the second, my Samsung Galaxy S8 shows no internet. Other devices work fine. But when I switched to mode router work fine.

- The first one has a different SSID name.
- The second and third same SSID and other option
- The channel is the same on all three.

So what is the best config for this setup?

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: My only question , in which one i disable dhcp

Comment: I already made my suggestion. That question unfortunately is currently deleted.

Comment: Why are you posting this stuff again [over here](https://superuser.com/q/1825753/167207)?

Answer (score 0):

DHCP should usually be disabled in all the boxes except the modem.
In other words, it should be disabled in all the boxes that function
as bridge or repeater or as an access-point, leaving only one DHCP
server in the network.

Especially if some devices may connect to the first or second boxes,
it's safer for the first modem box to be the DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

Since the second AP is actually a router (D-Link DSL-2750B) it seems it still has its routing function enabled. Also, you are probably connecting the LAN cable to its LAN port, not to its WAN port (or you changed the WAN port setting to a LAN port).

**Option 1**: If you disable the routing function on your second AP it should pass on the DHCP signal of the router and everything should work. It should have something called "bridge mode". This will deactivate all routing functions and should solve your problem. Basically, the same as you did on your first AP when you set it to bridge mode (just without the repeater mode).

Short background: An AP (a so-called layer 2 device) only needs an IP to connect to it for configuration purposes (the difference between a managed and an unmanaged device). For network connectivity purposes their IP should be irrelevant, but it is always a good idea to put them on the same subnet anyway unless you have a specific reason not to do that.

**Option 2**: As a workaround, that might solve your immediate problem (that your second AP still has routing functions), you can try to set the APs to the same subnet as the router. Make sure the the IPs are outside of the DHCP range or make sure to add a DHCP reservation for these devices on the router. But again, that is probably not your main problem.

Your configuration should be - for example:

```
Router:
IP 192.168.1.1/24 (24 ist subnet 255.255.255.0)
DHCP Range: 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200

AP1:
IP 192.168.1.2/24 (if it can be set)
bridge/repeater mode

AP2:
IP 192.168.1.3/24 (if it can be set)
bridge mode
```

**Option 3**: Alternatively, put the LAN cable into the WAN port of your second AP and turn on DHCP, but I wouldn't recommend it (unless you have some requirements for two routers in your LAN).