# No Internet access with DHCP, static IP is fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I have a setup with:

- Main router provides internet, `192.168.1.1`.
- An access point bridge mode, connected to the main router via wireless WAN, Radio mode: Repeater.
- And the second access point connected to the first AP with cable, `192.168.11.1` DHCP disabled, default gateway `192.168.1.1`.

My problem is some devices can't connect to the internet with DHCP only when I add static IP manually `192.168.11.x` gateway `192.168.11.1`, but the laptop works fine.

Even if I enabled DHCP in the second AP they got IP address from the main router `192.168.1.x`, not from the second AP.

---

**Update**: The first AP Netis WF-2429 connected to main router TP-Link TD-W8961N via wireless WAN, it is in mode bridge and acts like a repeater, IP LAN `192.168.1.102` reserved in main router static IP. DHCP is disabled. The second AP JAZZTEL ZXHN H298N connected to first AP via cable, DHCP disabled LAN IP `192.168.1.120`. Second AP not showed in main router to reserve IP Subnet mask `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: Try setting the AP to 192.168.1.2 with a DHCP reservation from the router, instead of on a different subnet.

Comment: All AP should belong to the same subnet `192.168.1.x`.

Comment: Turn on DHCP on the second and configure AP1 for range 1-127 & AP2 for range 128-255.  Tetsujin is correct.  192.168.1.2.  Most have range selection in the config.

Comment: So, main router 192.168.1.1  first AP 192.168.1.2 , Second AP 192.168.1.3?

Comment: Yes, router .1, AP1 .2 and AP2 .3, that would be correct. It might solve your immediate problem. But there is a more fundamental problem as well (please see my answer). Also please specify which devices you are using (manufacturer and model) and a network schematic would help as well. Which subnet are you using on each device, `255.255.255.0` (24 bit)? Please add the IP of the first AP (if it has one) and please add the IP range of your DHCP on the router (and on the second AP).

Comment: Why do you keep on posting variations on the same question? Your [last question is here](https://superuser.com/q/1824689/167207) and previous to that you had [an earlier question](https://superuser.com/q/1824624/167207) on the _same exact topic_ that you oddly deleted? There are valid answers to all of these questions; why are you playing games with this community?

Answer (score 0):

Since the second AP is actually a router (ZTE ZXHN H298N) it seems it still has its routing function enabled. Also, you are probably connecting the LAN cable to its LAN port, not to its WAN port (or you changed the WAN port setting to a LAN port).

**Option 1**
If you disable the routing function on your second AP it should pass on the DHCP signal of the router and everything should work. It should have something called "bridge mode". This will deactivate all routing functions and should solve your problem. Basically, the same as you did on your first AP when you set it to bridge mode (just without the repeater mode).

Short background: An AP (a so-called layer 2 device) only needs an IP to connect to it for configuration purposes (the difference between a managed and an unmanaged device). For network connectivity purposes their IP should be irrelevant, but it is always a good idea to put them on the same subnet anyway unless you have a specific reason not to do that.

**Option 2**
As Tetsujin suggests correctly: As a workaround, that might solve your immediate problem (that your second AP still has routing functions), you can try to set the APs to the same subnet as the router. Make sure the the IPs are outside of the DHCP range or make sure to add a DHCP reservation for these devices on the router. But again, that is probably not your main problem.

Your configuration should be - for example:

```
Router:
IP 192.168.1.1/24 (24 ist subnet 255.255.255.0)
DHCP Range: 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200

AP1:
IP 192.168.1.2/24 (if it can be set)
bridge/repeater mode

AP2:
IP 192.168.1.3/24 (if it can be set)
bridge mode
```

**Option 3**
Alternatively, put the LAN cable into the WAN port of your second AP and turn on DHCP, but I wouldn't recommend it (unless you have some requirements for two routers in your LAN).

Comment: The first AP netis WF-2429 connected to main router TD-W8961N via Wireless WAN, it is in mode bridge and acts like a repeater, IP Lan 192.168.1.102 reserved in main router static ip, DHCP Disabled 

The second AP JAZZTEL ZXHN H298N connected to first AP via cable, DHCP disabled lan ip 192.168.1.120 

Second AP not showed in main router to reserve ip 

Subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: @Brahim please this information to your question as well. Does it work if all devices are in the same subnet?

Comment: @Brahim I don't know JAZZTEL, is it a rebrand from your ISP? I only can find ZTE ZXHN H298N.

Comment: @Albin This is to the original poster: Why do you keep on posting variations on the same question? Your [last question is here](https://superuser.com/q/1824689/167207) and previous to that you had an [earlier question](https://superuser.com/q/1824624/167207) on the same exact topic that you oddly deleted? There are valid answers to all of these questions; why are you playing games with this community?