# Is there any way to setup 3 routers same network without double NAT?

Tags: networking, home-networking, nat

I have this configuration but I get double nat problem and my NAT type is set to strict is there any way to solve this and keep it looking like this.

```
      +------[Router+modem]--+
      |          |           |
      |          |           |
      |         tv1         tv2
  [Router 2]
      |
      |
  +---+---------------[Router 3] 
  |   |                   |
 tv3 tv4                  |
                  +-------+---------+
                  |                 |
                 pc                xbx
```

Comment: Is this post [related to this one](https://superuser.com/q/1824689/167207) by Brahim? Sounds familiar.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Disable the NAT and DHCP Server features of routers 2 & 3 so that they act as transparent bridges, not routers.

If either of those two extra routers don't have a way to turn off NAT and make the WAN port part of the LAN-side switch, then just stop using the WAN port on that one and connect even the "upstream" Ethernet cable to a LAN port on that router. On typical home gateway wireless routers, all of the LAN ports are always bridged together like a small Ethernet switch.

If either of those two extra routers don't have a way to disable their DHCP Server feature, see if you can configure a zero-length range of IP addresses for it to serve out. You want the main router to be the only DHCP Server on your network.

Doing this will give you one big single Ethernet LAN with a single IP subnet, and router 1 will continue to be a NAT gateway and DHCP server, now serving one big flat network. But your cabling topology will stay the same as your diagram as requested.

Comment: thank you ill try tthis but this will keep the wifi function active?

Comment: @mr.bolsitas Yes their wireless functionality will stay active.

Comment: @Spiff
you mentioned transperent bridge mode isnt this the same as a normal bridgemode?
do bridge mode disable wifi/lan functions?
 i couldnt solve the problem router 3 cant diable nat nor can i plug the ethernet cable in the lan one and when i don it wont give internet, would i have to get a newer router?

Comment: @mr.bolsitas, so it varies from device to device, and there may be many settings that affect the wifi functionality (for instance you could not use client/AP isolation while connecting the devices in some of the proposed wiring schemes). Personally I agree with Spiff that most Wifi routers will still provide wifi when in bridge/ap mode, but I have seen a few that won't. please consult your devices documentation.

Comment: @mr.bolsitas What is the make and model of router 3? Can you tell me why you say you can't connect the Ethernet cable into its LAN port instead of its WAN port? If the LAN ports are all full you could buy a small switch, which will probably be cheaper than buying a new AP (wireless router).

Comment: @Spiff my router 3 is ASUS RT-N12B1 when i connect the ethernet cable to the lan insted of wan/ethernet it only says disconnected and it wont provide internet the router has a router/ap/repeater mode but when i try to use ap it provides internet for 20 seconds then turn off and turn back on, my router 2 is NETGEAR Router WNR1000v3, and router/modem is HG8245H. i tried plugging in my xbox directly to router 1 but still says nat type strict and double nat detected. if i put all routers including router/modem1 into bridge mode will it fix my strict nat and double nat?