# I have 3 router but devices in the local network does not communicate with each other

Tags: networking, firewall, static-routes, routing-table

First router (195.105.1.1) is the one that was provided by ISP and we have 2 other routers. Both are connected to ISP router. Second router (195.105.1.2) has a local network which is 165.18.0.010. Third router (195.105.1.36) has a local network which is 10.0.0.2.

I cannot ping the local device in the second router from a local device in the third router. I tried different routing table rules and I was able to ping the second router (not the device) from a local device in the third router. Also, I cannot change any routing rules in the ISP router and I have disable firewall rules too.

Can someone tell what I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Is this question somehow related to [this other post](https://superuser.com/q/1824689/167207) by the user, [Brahim](https://superuser.com/users/1878475/brahim)? It seems awfully similar.

Answer (score 1):

Router 2 and Router 3 should not be acting as NAT gateways or DHCP Servers. They should simply be acting as network bridges/switches, plus Wi-Fi Access Points.

NAT, by default, blocks connection attempts initiated from the "public"/"WAN"/"upstream" side from reaching devices the "private"/"LAN"/"downstream" side. So it's okay to do NAT at the head of your network, but within your home network, you don't want any additional devices doing NAT unless you really know what you're doing.

Some routers let you disable their NAT gateway and DHCP Server features, and the WAN Ethernet port automatically becomes bridged in with the LAN Ethernet ports. If your routers let you do that, do it.

If Router 2 and Router 3 don't let you disable NAT, then you need to stop using their WAN ports. Instead, connect the cable from Router 1 to the downstream router's LAN port.

If Router 2 and Router 3 let you disable the DHCP Server feature, do it. If they don't let you disable it, then see if you can functionally disable it by giving it a zero-length range of IP addresses to serve out.

By making Routers 2 and 3 just act like transparent network bridges/switches (with integrated Wi-Fi AP), you turn your whole home network into a single hybrid wireless + wired Ethernet LAN. Router 1 at the head of the network will be acting as the only NAT gateway and DHCP Server for the whole network. You might even want to change all your APs to publish the same network name (SSID) with the same wireless security type and password (but different non-overlapping channels), so that your clients can seamlessly roam to whichever AP is nearest.

Comment: Why are there seemingly so many questions about 3 router setups out there?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I think a lot of median-sized single-family homes need 3 APs for proper coverage, and a fair fraction of people, not knowing better, get there by stringing together 3 home gateway wireless routers.

Comment: Odd coincidence… But hey!